# No parameters on DWR methods signature

Tags: java, dwr

I'm having some errors at runtime, from DWR methods with no parameters. The error looks like:

```
[exec] 12:21:56,372 ERROR [SignatureParser] Parameter mismatch parsing signatures section in dwr.xml on line: public String MyOwnClassName.myOwnDWRMethod()
```

How can I avoid this error? I mean, is there anything erroneous in the signature?

---

### Edit

`dwr.xml` has something like:

The signature is:

```
<signatures> <![CDATA[
  import MyControlClass;
  public String MyControlClass.selectItem();
]]>
</signatures>
```

The call is like:

```
function validateReport() {
MyControl.selectItem({callback:function(error) {alert('ok');}});
}
```

Comment: Could you post the method signature you're calling and the call itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the `function(error)`

```
function validateReport() 
{
    MyControl.selectItem({callback:function(error) {alert('ok');}});
}
```

The new callback function is expecting a value for the parameter **error**.

Try (without *error* as the functions parameter):

```
function validateReport() 
{
    MyControl.selectItem({callback:function() {alert('ok');}});
}
```

Thanks